# How to enable a non-global minor mode by default, on emacs startup?

Tags: emacs, mode

I want to enable `rainbow-mode` everytime I start emacs, rather than having to use `M-x rainbow-mode`.

I guess there is some command I put in my .emacs file.

I tried all of the following, but none of them worked:

```el
(require 'rainbow-mode)   

(rainbow-mode initialize)

(global-rainbow-mode)
```

More generally, how do I load any mode/package automatically on startup?

Comment: Caveat for rainbow mode specifically: globally enabling rainbow mode messes up something in at least some newly-created buffers, such that if you then toggle the mode off, the background of color-naming text is wrong (I observed this in Eshell buffers enhanced with proper terminal emulation provided by Eat - not sure if it happens more generally; for me that was enough of a nuisance that I chose to keep it off by default and just have a keybinding for toggling it).

Answer (score 52):

`rainbow-mode` isn't a global minor mode, so it needs to be enabled on a per-buffer basis.

I only use it for CSS, so I have:

```el
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'my-css-mode-hook)
(defun my-css-mode-hook ()
  (rainbow-mode 1))
```

If you *genuinely* want it to be global, everywhere, you can easily define a global minor mode yourself:

```el
(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-rainbow-mode rainbow-mode
  (lambda () (rainbow-mode 1)))

(my-global-rainbow-mode 1)
```

You can add any arbitrary logic to that `(lambda () (rainbow-mode 1))` function (which will be evaluated in every buffer) in order to decide whether or not to *actually* call `(rainbow-mode 1)` for a given buffer, so if you're comfortable with elisp then you can easily extend this approach to cover your specific requirements for the mode in question.

---

> More generally, how do I load any mode/package automatically on startup?

It can vary, but the approaches I've shown would suffice for most minor modes: Either you want them enabled whenever `MODE` is enabled (being some specific other mode name), in which case you can use the `MODE-hook` variable (which will always be available) as per the `css-mode-hook` example; or else you want the mode enabled permanently, in which case a global minor mode is a good approach (because you can toggle it on and off globally). Some minor modes are global by default (or provide global variants), but you can create your own if necessary, as per the `my-global-rainbow-mode` example.

Also be aware that modes can be *derived* from other modes, in which case *all* relevant `MODE-hook` hooks will be run (for details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380/324105). A common use-case is to use `prog-mode-hook` to enable functionality wanted for *all* the programming modes which are derived from it (which is most programming modes).

Remember that many (hopefully most) libraries and packages will provide usage instructions. If you can't find documentation, be sure to try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` to visit the library file, and then read through the comments at the top. There is often a very informative "Commentary" section, and sometimes this is the primary source of end-user documentation, and explain how to enable its functionality.

Comment: You can just do `(add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'rainbow-mode)` without going through `my-css-mode-hook`.

Comment: Stefan: only in Emacs 24, otherwise that toggles the mode, and I'm not inclined to assume that everyone has upgraded. (And in my case that function also does a bunch of other things, so I do need it :)

Comment: Thank-you! I used this to enable goto-address-mode globally. At the end, I put in .emacs: `(define-globalized-minor-mode global-goto-address-mode goto-address-mode
  (lambda () (goto-address-mode 1)))` and then by accident found the value on customize while checking the configuration for the mode, so in the end I let the global mode activation be handled by customize.

Comment: I used your solution in spacemacs (the global one) and it removed my color theme. I cannot enable it now :( How to undo this definition? How can I undefine the globalized minor mode?

Comment: @ashrasmun, that issue makes no sense to me (unless perhaps you don't have `rainbow-mode` installed at all), but you can toggle off the global mode using `M-x my-global-rainbow-mode` or evaluate `(my-global-rainbow-mode 0)`, after which it's not going to be doing anything.

Comment: @phils It makes no sense to me either, just as many things in emacs, but that's just one of the problems I have encountered as beginner spacemacs user. Thanks for additional info on the matter - I hope others can make use of it too!