# Derive from Lisp Mode, ignoring its hooks?

Tags: emacs, slime, major-mode

So I've created a major mode for a custom lisp by deriving from the standard Lisp Mode. However, when emacs enters it, it automatically activates slime-mode as well, which overrides most of my bindings. As far as I can tell, this happens because SLIME registers some hooks with Lisp Mode and my mode triggers them as well, but I'm not sure. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `define-derived-mode` then the body and mode hook for your parent mode are going to run.

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380 for details.

If you're enabling `slime-mode` in `lisp-mode-hook`, and your new mode is deriving from `lisp-mode`, then the *simplest* thing would be to *disable* `slime-mode` again in the mode hook for your derived mode.

---

Edit: Actually I believe you could prevent the mode hooks for the ancestor modes from running by manipulating `delayed-mode-hooks` in the *body* of your mode.

(You can't prevent the bodies of the ancestor modes from running.)

I recommend that you *don't* do this, though. I think if you find yourself wanting to mess with the derived mode mechanisms (especially if you're planning to share the code), then you shouldn't be using a derived mode at all.

You should probably take a cue from the implementations of `lisp-mode` vs `emacs-lisp-mode`. Rather than one being derived from the other, they are distinct modes (each derived from `prog-mode`). Their (independent) keymaps have a shared parent keymap, however, meaning that a lot of keybindings do the same things.

I suggest using that code as a template for creating a new lisp-ish major mode.

Comment: Well, that solves one specific instance of the problem that I happened to run into, but somebody else may have different Lisp Mode hooks that would break something again... Is there a more general solution to prevent this, other than duplicating Lisp Mode instead of deriving from it?

Comment: No, the whole point of derived modes is that they build on top of one another, and all the things which happen for `parent-mode` also happen for `child-mode`. You certainly shouldn't be looking for ways to stop *other people's* `lisp-mode` functionality from working in this scenario.

Comment: If you macroexpand your call to `derived-minor-mode`, you'll see the code which is actually generated. You could always use that as a basis for modification, if you still think that deriving from `lisp-mode` makes partial sense.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see why I shouldn't stop other people's lisp-mode functionality from working in a mode for a completely different language that just happens to use S-expressions. It being derived from lisp-mode is meant to be an implementation detail... However, since there seems to be no clean workaround, I'll just do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to inherit from a parent of lisp-mode.  Ideally, there should be a parent `lispish-mode` used by all Lisp-like major modes, but there's currently no such thing, so you'll have to use `prog-mode` and then manually setup/copy the things you want from `lisp-mode`.

I'd welcome a patch which adds a `lispish-mode` (even better if it comes with a better name), but so far everytime I looked at it I ended up finding that there's too much variation between Lispish modes for there to be much to be shared.

Comment: The question though comes up not only for lisp-mode, e.g. [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32414/prevent-hooks-from-parent-mode-in-derived-mode) is for text mode; and I locally stumbled upon it because of vala-mode derived from csharp-mode. I wonder if correct solution would rather be adding a function `add-mode-hook` that essentially gonna work the same as `add-hook`, except there would be additional parameter for the hook to not get triggered for derived modes.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways to go about attacking the problem

1. Change the hook function that is added to `lisp-mode-hook` so that it tests `(eq major-mode 'lisp-mode)` and is hence not executed in derived modes.
2. disable `lisp-mode-hook` while running your parent:

   ```
   (defun my-tamed-lisp-mode ()
     (let ((lisp-mode-hook nil))
       (lisp-mode)))

   (define-derived-mode my-custom-lisp-mode my-tamed-lisp-mode "CustomLisp"
     "Major mode for my custom Lisp."
     ...)
   ```