# Emacs: apply minor mode for all major modes

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I use the minor mode writeroom which I have set to be global, but this setting only makes the mode global for all text-modes. I can specify more modes in the settings. But is there something I can write to enable this minor mode for all major modes?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16048501/324105. You need to provide a link/details for this writeroom mode, because it's not part of Emacs. From your description it has some related options, but if you don't point us to it, we can't tell what you're actually using.

Comment: Calling this a duplicate, because you've asked much the same question about writeroom in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843082/emacs-set-writeroom-mode-as-default) (which garnered similar comments to my own).

Comment: Here is the link to the writeroom-mode that I am trying to use: [Writeroom](https://github.com/joostkremers/writeroom-mode)

Answer (score 3):

Add a hook to `find-file`:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'writeroom-mode)
```

Substitute `#'writeroom-mode` with whatever function you want to run.